# The animation does not trigger when react native clicks for the first time

Tags: typescript, react-native

Why does the animation effect I set always have no effect when I click it for the first time? and What is the typescript of ref binding animation in react native？

```
const Test = () => {
  const messRef: any = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

  return (
    <View>
      <Animated.Text
        onPress={() => {
          Animated.timing(messRef, {
            toValue: show ? 200 : 0,
            duration: 1000,
            useNativeDriver: false,
          }).start();
          setShow(!show);
        }}
        style={{
          color: messRef.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 100],
            outputRange: ["orange", "blue"],
          }),
        }}
      >
        Everything you do in life stems from either fear or love
      </Animated.Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in

```
toValue: show ? 200 : 0,
```

For the first time value of show will be false and when you click first time
value of toValue will be 0 again.
Make it

```
toValue: !show ? 200 : 0,
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it has been successfully resolved